# Is there a way to create rails app within gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to make my gem work as an application: when I run `rails server` inside gem's directory I'd like to see it working just like regular application. But still able to include this gem via Gemfile of any other rails app.

Is it even possible?

Comment: try going to `%APP_PATH%/test/dummy` and run `rails s` there.

Comment: Running anything from within a gem is highly unusual. Why not build a [Rails engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) you can load into a skeleton Rails app?

Comment: @tadman, the thing is.. I use browserify-rails to create my own awesome frontend build, but it works really bad from within engines, thus I want to be able to bundle it in other projects, but keep working on it without skeleton apps..
Pretty unusual, right

Comment: Actually having to go into a gem's directory to do something like that is usually a sign something's wrong. You could make your own script, like `myengine server` which would take care of launching it properly, but that still seems wrong. Usually apps like this require support for some kind of configuration even if the defaults work most of the time, and it's not really practical or sane to edit the gem itself. A minimal Rails app, like how errata suggests below, is the best practice here.

Answer (score 2):

Look into rails engines. With full engines you can package apps in a way that they can be pulled into other apps. See refineryCMS for an example of this.

Here is an article on creating an api that can be mounted within another app: https://netguru.co/blog/rails-api-as-an-engine

With a full engine the parent app will inherit the routes defined by the engine. With a mountable engine they are namespaced by default.
If you want the app to behave as a standalone app you can do something like:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine => "/
```